# adding in m2m items that have been filtered in a form with a Django Generic Class View

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have an app that has two models in it. The first is called scenario. The second is called solutions. There is a M2M between scenarios and solutions. You can have any number of solutions belonging to scenarios and visa versa. Pretty straightforward.

The trick is, everything is filtered on the user. So I don't want to see the solutions or scenarios that other's have when I'm working.

I've written a view that is a CreateView. It adds a filtered list of solutions to the context. Once it's in the context, I loop it in the template to get the id. I add that to the form.

The problem I'm having is in the form_valid method.

How do I add the selected items to the save, so that they are added to the scenario?

Here's my view:

```
class ScenarioCreate(CreateView):

    success_url = reverse_lazy('scenario_list')
    template_name = "gps/create_scenario_form.html"
    model = Scenario
    form_class = ScenarioCreateForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ScenarioCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['solution_list'] = Solution.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.solutions = form.cleaned_data['solutions'] # <= what goes here?
        self.object.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ScenarioCreate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I had assumed that cleaned_data would magically solve my set issue.

I have two questions.

1. How do I get that save to work?
2. Am I think about adding to the context correctly, or is there a better way?

All help appreciated.

UPDATE: Adding ScenarioCreateForm

```
class ScenarioCreateForm(ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        exclude = ('user', 'created')
```

Comment: Update, should I be doing this with get_initial() in the view?

Comment: can you post your ScenarioCreateForm?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the form